# restrict bitcoin core to tor

Tags: bitcoin-core, tor

I run both bitcoind and bitcoin-qt calling with
`-proxy=127.0.0.1:9050`

Is this enough for Bitcoin Core to route any communication through Tor, or does this risk any name resolution or something being queried directly instead of channeled in Tor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this enough for Bitcoin Core to route any communication through Tor, or does this risk any name resolution or something being queried directly instead of channeled in Tor?

According to [doc/tor.md](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/tor.md), `proxy` option sets the proxy for DNS requests;                   with `onion` they will not route over Tor. So using `-proxy=127.0.0.1:9050` should be enough to route DNS requests through Tor.

You can also use `-dns=0` to disable DNS lookups for `-addnode`, `-seednode` and `-connect` values.